# Flex height not working in Firefox/Edge like it does in Chrome (and IE...)

Tags: html, css, firefox, flexbox, microsoft-edge

In Chrome, Safari and surprisingly IE 11 if a container has `display: flex; flex-direction: column; height: 100%` you can set the child to `flex: 1` and have it take as much height as it can without going beyond the bounds of it's container's height.

That allows me to put scrollbars not on the page but on the `.scrollable` container very easily.

Here's the example:

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/XYyLYE

or

```css
body, html {
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 120px;
}

.container {
  width: 500px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  margin: 0 auto;
  height: 100%;
}

.header {
  background: cyan;
  flex: 0 0 50px;
  margin: 5px 0
}

.content {
  flex: 1;
  display: flex;
}

.scrollable {
  width: 100%;
  overflow: auto;
}

.item {
  background: red;
  height: 10px;
  width: 100%;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="header">Header</div>
  <div class="content">
    <div class="scrollable">
      <div class="item"></div>
      <div class="item"></div>
      <div class="item"></div>
      <div class="item"></div>
      <div class="item"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

However, running this in Chrome and Edge I'm forced to do the following on my `.content` container:
* remove the `flex: 1;` line 
* add `height: calc(100% - 60px)` where 60px is my header's height + margin

Why is FF and Edge behaving differently, and how can I avoid using height calculations?

Thanks,

Comment: For those that want to see a codepen with the FF/Edge solution (which ofc works fine on other browsers too but not idea): https://codepen.io/anon/pen/EROqaG

Comment: what if you replace `flex: 0 0 50px;` by `height:50px`

Comment: IE11 [**doesn't fully support flexbox**](https://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox) yet. You'll need fallback behaviour if you want to support IE.

Comment: @TemaniAfif didnt work :(

Comment: @ObsidianAge that's the thing, IE works fine. It's MS Edge that doesn't.

Comment: got it ! `min-height: 0;` will fix it ... it somehow related to the shrink past content size

Comment: @TemaniAfif I was just thinking how long time its gonna take before you figured that one out :)

Comment: what in the hell?! Why would it make do that... it works!

Comment: Put that in the answers, I'll mark it as Answered mate!

Comment: @LGSon haha :p since it behave differently within browser I will need time :p

Comment: Because a flex item's default `min-height` is `auto`, and won't allow it to be smaller than its content, and by setting it to `0` fix that (and FF and Edge won't comply w/o it)

Comment: As stated by @TemaniAfif, just add `min-height: 0` to `.content` ([revised demo](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/pKQMbL)). It's explained in the duplicate post (see, in particular, the "Browser Rendering Notes" section in my answer).

Comment: I would add it as an answer but since it behave differently I don't have the explanation of this behavior and the min-height  is well explained here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36247140/why-dont-flex-items-shrink-past-content-size

Comment: @Michael_B but why it behave differently? a bug?

Comment: Thank you all! That makes sense, I did not know about the `min-height: auto` of flex items...

Comment: @TemaniAfif, it's explained in my answer in the dupe. At the bottom, under "Browser Rendering Notes".

Comment: @Michael_B yes right ... well you answers are very long so not easy to remember everything :p